# PostgreSQL JSON - String_agg in json data with multiple objects

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have create table with Json datatype field in PostgreSQL.

Also i have inserted data with multiple object in json data

like this

```
[
    {
        "Type": "1",
        "Amount": "1000",
        "Occurrence": 2,
        "StartDate": "1990-01-19",
        "EndDate": "1999-04-03"
    },
    {
        "Type": "2",
        "Amount": "2000",
        "Occurrence": 2,
        "StartDate": "1984-11-19",
        "EndDate": "1997-09-29"
    }
]
```

Now i have to retrieve my data as per below formate in single row like string_agg() function output.

```
Type    Amount
1--2    1000-2000
```

also i have checked inbuilt function for json in PostgreSQL (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/) but not find any solutions for the same.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: i am using Postgres 10.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to unnest the array and aggregate the individual keys:

The following assumes you have some kind of primary key column on the table (in addition to your JSON column):

```
select t.id, 
       string_agg(x.element ->> 'Type', '-') as types,
       string_agg(x.element ->> 'Amount', '-') as amounts
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.data) as x(element)
group by t.id;
```

`jsonb_array_elements()` extracts each array element and the main query then aggregates that back per ID using string_agg().

The above assumes your column is defined with the type `jsonb` (which it should be). If it is not, you need to use `json_array_elements()` instead.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fc014917ebf8ae9a11bd51716a339c90)

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, perfect answer as what i need, Also one quick question should i use json or jsonb for this type of data?

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) "*In general, most applications should prefer to store JSON data as `jsonb`*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, what if two json columns in same table, currently its duplicate data with use of cross join, i have updated in code here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f8244e462886fd3ca0b2bcb8d9285b56 for this scenario